# Determine real size of UIView during UIViewController's life cycle

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm using iOS 4.3.

I've got a UIViewController with a view that just has a UIToolbar and a subview that covers the rest of the view. The main UIView has springs and struts to make it conform to any shape and the subview does as well. The xib is in Portrait orientation by default.

I put this UIViewController into the right side of my UISplitViewController. My iPad is in landscape orientation before I show this view controller and stays in landscape orientation the entire time... so to be clear, I'M NOT CHANGING ORIENTATION.

The xib is 768w and 1004h, so my subview is 768w and 960h.

In `-viewDidLoad` my subview is 768x960.

In `-viewWillAppear` my subview is 768x960.

In `-viewDidAppear` my subview is 768x960.

But when I actually SEE it on my iPad, the right side of the UISplitViewController is 704px wide (as it should be) and my view as well as my subview are verifiably only 704px wide.

However, at no point in the code or View Controller life cycle was I able to query `self.view` or my subview and see the width was 704px.

I need to make some changes based on the size of my overall view, because my subview is a UIScrollView and I want to alter the scrollView.contentSize based on the REAL size of my `self.view`.

There has got to be someway in the View Controller life cycle where I can get the real size of my view. I've tried the `frame` and the `bounds` but they both show 768x906 all the time.

```
NSLog(@"scroll view frame=%@ bounds=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.scrollView.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(self.scrollView.bounds));

NSLog(@"view frame=%@ bounds=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));

UIViewController *detailVC = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"splitview frame=%@ bounds=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(detailVC.view.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(detailVC.view.bounds));
```

Comment: Add a button that triggers an action that logs the view size.  Is it correct when you tap the button?

Comment: Yes. It is correct after the view is truly visible and I tap a button.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on the simulator under iOS 5 or iOS 6.  Tiny test project here: https://github.com/mayoff/stackoverflow-12946064  The frame is correct in `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm running in an iOS4.3 simulator. I've updated my post.

Comment: Does it behave differently in iOS 5?

Comment: Yes. It works as I would expect it to work in iOS5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the **UIViewController** method `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. This is the best place to update your scroll view.

Keep in mind that your view controller will start in portrait. At some point it will be rotated to landscape. For debugging purposes you may wish to override the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` methods.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I need this to work in iOS4 and viewWillLayoutSubviews doesn't exist in iOS4.